# CSS-support in IntelliJ IDEA CE (Community Edition)?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any sort of freemium/freeware plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA CE that supports CSS?

I have a license for one of their other suites but I primarily use this one. It sort of drives me nuts to have to switch applications just to have CSS syntax highlighting, etc. when I need to edit a CSS file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CSS editing in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338582/how-to-enable-css-editing-in-intellij)